# Combining firestore with firebase functions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I have no clue how to combine firestore with firebase functions i want to check some fields in document and return some data if field equals sth.

My code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { collection, getDoc, query, where, addDoc } = require("firebase-admin/firestore");


const firebaseConfig = {
...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
const roomsRef = db.collection("rooms");


exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var { uid, name, password } = request.body;
    var q = query(roomsRef, where("creator_uid", "==", uid), where("name", "==", name));
    if (q)
        var rooms = getDoc(q);
    if (rooms.exist)
        response.send(rooms.data().name)
    else
        response.send("nie zadziala xD")
});
```

My error:

[image]

What possibly could go wrong? how to combine firestore with functions properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved that on my own :) code below if someone have simillar problem

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { uid, name, password } = req.body;
    const nameRef = admin.firestore()
        .collection('rooms').where("name", "==", name);
    const uidRef = nameRef.where("creator_uid", "==", uid);
    const passwordRef = uidRef.where("password", "==", password);

    passwordRef.get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc) {
            res.json(doc.docs.map((docx) => { return docx.data() }));
        }
        else {
            res.json([]);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        //Internal server error
        console.log("Error", err)
        res.json(err);
    });
});

/* EXAMPLE POST

curl -X POST https://us-central1-test-36302.cloudfunctions.net/xxx
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"name":"xxxa","uid": "B2Xidd3Vw1PL9Kyt5ERFXCjniuF3",
    "password": "xxxx"}'

*/
```